# Found Possible Solution via SatisfyImports - Is There a Better Way?

Tags: mef

Is there a better way to hook up dependencies??
This relies on the singleton App.Current and exposing a function that exposes the _container.SatisfyImports.

Is there a more MEF-tastic way of doing things?

Here is part of my main application class

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private CompositionContainer _container;    

    ....

    public void SatisfyImportsOnce(Object satifyMe)
    {
        _container.SatisfyImportsOnce(satisfyMe);    
    }
}
```

Here is a test class instantiated long after ComposeParts is called...

```
public class TestClass
{
    public TestClass()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Created a TestClass");

       ((Microsoft.Samples.XFileExplorer.App)App.Current).SatisfyImportsOnce(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am in a similar situation in a WPF application where I want the MainWindow instance to import MEF exports.  Since MEF does not create the MainWindow instance, it will not satisfy the imports unless you tell it to.

The way you are doing it will work if you do not want your instance to be registered for recomposition.  If you do want recomposition, you should call [ComposeParts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.attributedmodelservices.composeparts%28VS.100%29.aspx).

Recomposition will update the imports in your class if and when they change.